# Ошибка при открытии крестиков ноликов

Tags: python

После запуска программы высвечивается на половину темное окно.Как быть? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pygame
import sys

def check_win(mas,sign):
    zeroes = 0
    for row in mas:
        zeroes+= row.count(0)
        if row.count(sign)==3:
            return sign
    for col in range(3):
        if mas[0][col]==sign and mas[1][col]==sign and mas[2][col]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][0]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][2]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign:
            return sign
    if zeroes==0:
        return 'Piece'
    return False


pygame.init()
size_block = 100
margin = 15
width = height = size_block*3 + margin*4

size_window = (width,height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size_window)
pygame.display.set_caption('Крестики нолики')

black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
mas = [ [0]*3 for i in range(3)]
query = 0
game_over = False
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over:
            x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            col = x_mouse // (size_block+margin)
            row = y_mouse // (size_block + margin)
            if mas[row][col] == 0:
                if query%2==0:
                    mas[row][col] = 'x'
                else:
                    mas[row][col] = 'o'
                query+=1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            game_over = False
            mas = [[0] * 3 for i in range(3)]
            query=0
            screen.fill(black)

    if not game_over:
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                    if mas[row][col]=='x':
                        color = red
                    elif mas [row][col]=='o':
                        color = green
                    else:
                        color = white
            x = col*size_block + (col+1) *margin
            y = row * size_block + (row + 1) * margin
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,size_block,size_block))
            if color==red:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+5,y+5), (x+size_block-5,y+size_block-5), 3)
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+size_block-5,y+5), (x+5,y+size_block-5), 3)
            elif color == green:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x+size_block//2,y+size_block//2),size_block//2-3,3)
    if (query-1) %2==0:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'x')
    else:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'o')

    if game_over:
        screen.fill(black)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('stxingkai', 80)
        text1 = font.render(game_over, True, white)
        text_rect = text1.get_rect()
        text_x = screen.get_width() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        text_y = screen.get_height() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        screen.blit(text1, [text_x, text_y])

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подумайте над этой строкой. Что у вас тут со скобками?

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x,y,) (x+size_block,y+size_block), 3)
                                    ^^
```

Сейчас вы пытаетесь вызвать кортеж `(x,y,)` как функцию и передать этой функции параметры `(x+size_block,y+size_block)`

Полагаю, что в правильном коде запятая и скобка должны поменяться местами:

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x,y), (x+size_block,y+size_block), 3)
                                    ^^
```

Comment: Спасибо,  надеюсь в будущем буду учитывать это

Comment: @pacanchik_s_tysu Ошибка 'object is not callable' обычно бывает когда что-то с круглыми скобками намудрили и они не там, где надо )

Comment: Я пересоздал вопрос, можете помочь?